# HttpClient fails with System.ArgumentException when using ClientCert -> Client cert not sent

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8.1

I am running into an issue using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient, in a Windows Phone app. I am working with a server that requires a client certificate. When I call SendRequestAsync() I get a "System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range."

I am setting the ClientCertificate to use via a HttpFilter object.

I am running Wireshark on the server and I am able to decrypt the traffic via the server key.  In Wireshark I see a *TLSv1.2 Server Hello, Certificate, Certificate Request* packet, and the server requests a certificate that is issued by the same CA that issued the certificate I passed.  Right after I see the Certificate Request packet, I see the client send a *FIN, ACK* packet.

Note that I do two HTTPS requests.  The first is a HTTP OPTIONS request, and for that request I do see the client certificate being passed (I do get a HTTP 200 response on this one).  It is when I do the second request with a HTTP POST that I get the failure.  Both use the same code path for sending the request to the server.

Any ideas on how I can get the HttpClient to use the certificate?

Here is the code I am using:

```
IHttpFilter httpFilter = null;
HttpRequestMessage requestMsg = null;
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
HttpClient client = null;

try
{
    httpFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    httpFilter.AutomaticDecompression = true;
    httpFilter.ClientCertificate = _MyCertificate;
    httpFilter.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

    client = new HttpClient(httpFilter);

    requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage();
    requestMsg.RequestUri = _Uri;
    requestMsg.Method = _HttpMethod;
    if (_PostData != null && _PostData > 0)
    {
        var postStream = new MemoryStream(_PostData);
        requestMsg.Content = new HttpStreamContent(postStream.AsInputStream());
        requestMsg.Content.Headers.Add(HeaderContentType, _ContentType);
        requestMsg.Content.Headers.Add(HeaderContentLength, _ContentLength.ToString());     
    }

    HttpCompletionOption completionOption = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead;
    requestTask = client.SendRequestAsync(requestMsg, completionOption).AsTask(request.CancelTokenSource.Token);
    responseMessage = await requestTask;

     // .. process response
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // handle errors
}
finally
{
    if (requestMsg != null)
    {
        requestMsg.Dispose();
    }
    if (responseMessage != null)
    {
        responseMessage.Dispose();
    }
    if (httpFilter != null)
    {
        httpFilter.Dispose();
    }
    if (client != null)
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error? Call stack? HResult?

Comment: What are the values of _Uri, _HttpMethod, _ContentType, _ContentLenth, HeaderContentType, HeaderContentLength.

Comment: I am getting a HRESULT of 0x80070057 in the exception and requestTask.Exception has a HRESULT of 0x80131500.  Using Wireshark, the data I am posting is coming out fine (I am posting wbxml data to an Exchange server).  The issue is more that the IIS server is doing a key exchange and is requesting a cert, but then instead of sending my configured cert, a FIN, ACK is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being with setting the content-length.  I change the way I set the post data and it seems to work now:

```
if (_PostData != null && _PostData > 0)
{
   requestMessage.Content = new HttpBufferContent(request.PostData.AsBuffer());
   requestMessage.Content.Headers.Add(HeaderContentType, request.ContentType); 
}
```

Comment: yep, HttpBufferContent works better than HttpStreamContent, don't know why...!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the client certificate your are supplying has associated private key.